# Angular 2 App running under a relative URL

Tags: angular, single-page-application

My client has asked me to deploy an Angular 2 app to his server. Unfortunately the app will need to run under a relative URL: e.g `http://website/a/b/c`

Angular is throwing an error can't match any roots with `/a/b/c` as it's obviously processing the URL and trying to route the client.

How can I get around this?

Comment: `<base href="/a/b/c">` in index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has a support for it.

In main html file, you have to add:

```
<head>
   <base href="/a/b/c">
</head>
```